# Generate random data from arbitrary CDF in R?

Tags: r, random, cdf

I have an arbitrary CDF that is applied to a point estimate. I have a number of these point estimates with associated CDFs, that I need to simulate random data for a Monte Carlo simulation.

The CDF I'm generating by doing a spline fit to the arbitrary points provided in a table. For example, the quantile 0.1 is a product of 0.13 * point estimate. The quantile 0.9 is a product of 7.57 * point estimate. It is fairly crude and is based on a large study comparing these models to real world system -- ignore that for now please.

I fit the CDF using a spline fit as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZks0.jpg).

If I take the derivative of this, I get the shape of the pdf ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHUxA.jpg)).

I modified the function "samplepdf" found here, [Sampling from an Arbitrary Density](http://blog.quantitations.com/tutorial/2012/11/20/sampling-from-an-arbitrary-density/), as follows:

```
samplecdf <- function(n, cdf, spdf.lower = -Inf, spdf.upper=Inf) {
  my_fun <- match.fun(cdf)
  invcdf <- function(u) {
    subcdf <- function(t) my_fun(t) - u
    if (spdf.lower == -Inf) 
      spdf.lower <- endsign(subcdf, -1)
    if (spdf.upper == Inf) 
      spdf.upper <- endsign(subcdf)
    return(uniroot(subcdf, c(spdf.lower, spdf.upper))$root)
  }
 sapply(runif(n), invcdf)
}
```

This seems to work, OK - when I compare the quantiles I estimate from the randomly generated data they are fairly close to the initial values. However, when I look at the histogram something funny is happening at the tail where it is looks like my function is consistently generating more values than it should according to the pdf. This function consistently does that across all my point-estimates and even though I can look at the individual quantiles and they seem close, I can tell that the overall Monte Carlo simulation is demonstrating higher estimates for the 50% percentile than I expect. Here is [a plot of my histogram of the random samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x18oN.jpg).

Any tips or advice would be very welcome. I think the best route would be to fit an exponential distribution to the CDF, but I'm struggling to do that. All "fitting" assumes that you have data that needs to be fitted -- this is more arbitrary than that.

Comment: You could sample from CDF, no need to use PDF. Basically, sampled value v = CDF^-1(U(0,1)), a.k.a. inverse CDF sampling.  U(0,1) you could get from `runif()`. If you use low-order spline, CDF should be easily invertible.

Comment: Here is the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: I will take a look at that. That is the method that I think my function is using in my post, but I should understand it more. When I changed the spline method from "fmm" to "natural" it helped a little but still doesn't look right. Do I need to somehow anchor my spline to be within 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of the method - you have to have CDF monotonically growing on the domain [a...b] (either or both could be -+infinity), with `y` equal to 0 at x=a and `y` equal to 1 at x=b. THen to get inverse function you basically rotate it by 90 degrees, so your domain is [0...1] and co-domain  is [a...b]. Select uniformly `x` from `runif` and for this `x` draw vertical line and find corresponding `y` - that is it.

Comment: And from you CDF graph looks like it is not well defined - it is not reaching 1 at the right corner of your graph

Comment: Alternative option: deconstruct your CDF into the PDF and use `sample(x,samplesize,replace=TRUE,PDF)`  where `x` is the bin sizes corresponding to your discrete `PDF` . This is handy when your CDF or PDF is discrete and ugly enough that you don't want to try fitting to a function or even a spline.